# cannot use sudo on company issued mac - workarounds?

Tags: macos, sudo, macbook-pro, root

I cannot use root/sudo on my Macbook - is there a way to create some sort of artificial root user, so that the sudo command, when issued by tools and software on my machine, can not break stuff?

Comment: "Company issued" implies that if you work *around* IT restrictions, it might cost you your job. Ask IT staff for an approved way to solve the issue so you can perform your work!

Comment: The whole point of restricted permissions is that they're… restricted. If they did it properly, there's literally no way round it. You can't even boot to single user or from an external drive to get around it these days. If you need fewer restrictions, you need to ask IT. BTW, macOS doesn't really use root. sudo or full admin perms is what you need.